# Unknowingly ran an infinite loop in terminal

Tags: terminal

I copied the below code from some random source to my terminal and ran:

```
while sleep 1;
  do tput sc;
  tput cup 0 $(($(tput cols)-29));
  date;
  tput rc;
done &
```

The code is to show a running clock at the top right corner of the terminal. The snippet worked very well and exactly did what I wanted it to, but now I just want to end this loop and get rid of the clock.

Also, I need to understand the above code. I've some idea, as I know what `tput` command does, but still there're many dots which I'm not able to connect.

Comment: You can run `jobs` in your session to list active background jobs and then put it to foreground by typing `fg <job number>`. After type Ctrl+C to stop this infinite loop. This scenario is working only in terminal that run snippet.

Comment: Thank you very much, a very clean way of getting rid of the loop. This should become the accepted answer.

Comment: You are welcome! I put it as answer bellow.

Comment: Note that simply closing the terminal window will also terminate all running jobs attached to it.

Comment: You have two questions here.  Can you split the 2nd, to a new question.

Comment: That's nothing-- I once foolishly ran a background job that spawned itself twice.  Nearly crashed the entire system (mainframe) with the number of jobs that  tried to run concurrently!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can run `jobs` command in your session to list active background jobs and then put them to foreground by typing `fg <job number>`. Then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop this infinite loop.

This scenario is working only in terminal that run snippet.

---

Explanation:

`tput sc` - save cursor position.

`tput cup 0 $(($(tput cols)-29))` - move cursor to position `0` of Y axis and `(count of screen columns minus 29)` of X axis.

`date` - just print current date.

`tput rc` - restore cursor position.

`while sleep 1; ... do ... ; done` - loop with delay of 1 second.

Type `help while` to know more about `while` loop in shell and follow to [man 1 tput](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tput) or [tldp tput doc](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html) to know how tput works.

Comment: I still would like to know how did the code do what it did.

Comment: @KartikChauhan I put some explanation also.

Comment: @KartikChauhan You are right! Thank's! I've just fixed this.

Comment: `kill %1` (or a different number if there are multiple jobs) is an alternative to `fg` + `Ctrl-C`